# How do you float divs to the left?

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm trying to be a better html coder, so I have decided to get away from table layout.
And use div layout instead, but I'm getting issues  positioning stuff using divs.

On my page I'm trying to add three images and text to them, but they won't align using float, instead they are cascading.

here's my markup:

```
<style>
.left
{
   float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left">
    <img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" /> 
    </div>
     <div>
         some text
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" />
    </div>
    <div>
        some text
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <img src="Images/image.JPG" alt=""  class="left" />
    </div>
    <div>
        some text
    </div>
</body>
```

Im hoping one of you can point the problem, (Help! I dont want to go back to nasty tables! :))

Here's a picture:

[image]

EDIT:
I would like to align them vertically

Paul Roub's answer is the closest, but just need to space them up.

Comment: add display:inline-block; or display:block;

Comment: How do you want the text to be positioned in relation to the images?

Comment: the image to the left, the text to the right

Comment: And then each image+text pair in new line?

Comment: yes so it will  be 3 rows

Comment: Downvoters why? I am asking legit question

Comment: Can you please consider my answer? It's the easiest and most clean approach.

Comment: Check my answer below, the second JSfiddle.

Comment: @matewka It might be easy and clean, but it wont scale at all.

Comment: You didn't say you want it to scale. Do you want the text to not wrap into new line when it doesn't fit?

Comment: @matewka I'm not the OP, I was just commenting that yours is easy and clean, but it wont scale very well.

Comment: I didn't notice :) Well, let the OP decide.

Comment: @matewka Lol, yes he shall, if he didn't leave that is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `divs` at all. Try this **HTML**:

```
<img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" /> 
some text

<img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" /> 
some text

<img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" /> 
some text
```

And this **CSS** to put your text aligned with the top of the image:

```
.left {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you want some space between the pictures then your CSS should look like:

```
.left {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* that gives you 10px of space at the bottom of an image*/
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhgpr/1/) of the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can read up on this, I would like to be more productive with this.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: float both the text and image divs left, and clear floats on the images:

```
.left {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.left + div {
 float: left;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/knbBJ

Comment: this is the closest from what I need I just need to space them out , I tried <br />

Comment: Consider adding `margin-bottom: 10px;` (or whatever spacing you like) to `.left`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gGxEn/

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <p><img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="left" />someusce consequat ipsum nunc, nec condimentum dui cursus id. Ut consequat scelerisque urna, non porttitor tortor blandit vitae. Fusce scelerisque sem congue risus condimentum.
</p>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <p><img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="left" />some usce consequat ipsum nunc, nec condimentum dui cursus id. Ut consequat scelerisque urna, non porttitor tortor blandit vitae. Fusce scelerisque sem congue risus condimentum.
</p>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <p><img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="left" />someusce consequat ipsum nunc, nec condimentum dui cursus id. Ut consequat scelerisque urna, non porttitor tortor blandit vitae. Fusce scelerisque sem congue risus condimentum.
</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.left
{
   float: left;
    width:33%;
}

.left img{
    padding:5px;
}
```

If you want them stacked on top of one another, add `clear:both` to the `left` class.

here is another fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gGxEn/1/

Comment: No I would like them align vertically , I will update my post

Comment: Check the second fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your text needs to be inside the floated div

```
<div class="left">
 <img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" /> 
 text
</div>

<div class="left">
 <img src="Images/image.JPG" alt="" class="left" />
 text
</div>

<div class="left">
 <img src="Images/image.JPG" alt=""  class="left" />
 text
</div>
```

Comment: I want to align them vertically, yours will put them horizontally

Comment: In that case why are you floating them, if you don't they will stack vertically on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is making float:left and then clear:both.

```
<style>
    .inline { float:left; }
    .clear { clear:both; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inline">
        <img src="http://umbra.nascom.nasa.gov/images/latest_aia_171_icon.gif">
        <p><center>Text 1</center></p>
    </div>
    <div class="inline">
        <img src="http://umbra.nascom.nasa.gov/images/latest_aia_171_icon.gif">
        <p><center>Text 2</center></p>
    </div>
    <div class="inline">
        <img src="http://umbra.nascom.nasa.gov/images/latest_aia_171_icon.gif">
        <p><center>Text 3</center></p>
    </div>
    <br class="clear">
</body>
```

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aefsp/). I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yo want [**something like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/fR4ff/)

**CSS**

```
.img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fqct5Us.gif"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<div class="img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fqct5Us.gif"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<div class="img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fqct5Us.gif"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
```

Its pretty simple, just don't float the container of text.